# Wrap many internal modules for exporting in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, amd

I am looking at using typescript within node, and am currently used to using typescript via the `///<reference.../>` syntax purely using internal modules. However with larger projects this can get unwieldy as you can have modules referencing other modules which all have interlinking references.

So for this node project I was thinking about trying to group all logical *components* as internal modules/classes much like before, so they will all internally reference each other, but expose them via one external module which would expose the underlying classes etc.

This way the syntax would be very similar of nodes existing requiring mechanisms, like:

```
import database = require("my-external-db-module.ts");
var connection = new database.Connection(someUrl);
```

rather than

```
///<reference path="my-internal-db-modules.ts" />
var connection = new Database.Connection(someUrl);
```

And I imagine the syntax would be something like:

```
///<reference path="all-my-internal-module-files-etc.ts" />
///<reference path="..." />
export module SomeExposingModule
{
   // Not quite sure what to put in here to expose the internal modules
}
```

So are there any sort of best practices around this sort of thing or any others who have done something similar, or does everyone just stick to using internal modules for complex stuff?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if this is bad practice or not but here is how I solved my problem.

First a quick summary of the problem again:

I have multiple files all logically grouped under a namespace, for example `Framework` then all files under there will be `Framework.*`, such as `Framework.Database` or `Framework.UnitOfWork`. Then these are all compiled via `tsc --out framework.js ...` so I get all of this outputted into a `framework.js` file.

Now the above sounds fine, however it does not allow you to export modules when using --out because it spans multiple files, so for node to work I need to export the modules somehow, so I basically appended an extra typescript file which manually does this for me in the compilation:

```
// exporter.ts
module.exports = Framework;
```

So providing this is the last file added to the `tsc` compilation you will end up with something like:

```
// Framework.js
var Framework;
(function (Framework) {
    // lots of good stuff
})(Framework || (Framework = {}));
module.exports = Framework;
```

So this will export the internal modules fine and the export declaration will be included now because of the exporter.ts file which is now included.

So I am not sure if this is bad practice but this allows me to have the best of both worlds, a re-usable module which is laid out with namespaces and is spread across a sensible file structure, and a compiled single module which can be included either by references or by nodejs require.

So the usage would look like:

```
var Framework = require("./framework");
var database = new Framework.Database.DbConnection();
```

Comment: In my case, with a Unix build script, I found it easier to achieve the same result with the following command:

echo 'module.exports = Framework;' >> Framework.js

Answer (score 2):

There are some ideas that help to smooth some of these issues.

If you have a lot of references, you can use a reference file to manage them. For example:

references.ts

```
///<reference path="a.ts" />
///<reference path="b.ts" />
///<reference path="c.ts" />
///<reference path="d.ts" />
```

All other files...

```
///<reference path="references.ts" />
```

You now have a central list of your references, which is much easier than weaving lists of references at the top of each file.

In your specific case, I would be more inclined to use `import` statements and get NodeJS to load modules for me - and I would group modules using the file system.

Comment: My problem is not so much about managing the references, as in my current project I do as you say and it works *ok*, so I have a load of files sprinkled across the project and I use a build script to generate kind of project level reference lookup files. The problem I get with this approach though is that if I have a database project and a logic project which depends on the database, using the above approach my logic.js compiled file contains both the content of the database ts files AND the logic ts files, whereas I am hoping to use external modules to avoid this extra compilation *guff*

Comment: Sorry to double post comments but to continue, so to avoid this snowball effect of internal `///<reference/>` includes I was hoping in this new project to adopt external modules so the logic.js would only contain the compiled js from the logic files, and would just reference the other module, creating a simple kind of runtime dependency not a compile time one. I have mentioned the problems of the above approach in an issue I raised with the good folks managing Typescript. https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/923 I was hoping to sidestep that problem described with external modules

Comment: Yes, in your case I would fully commit to loading external modules on demand as it leans on built-in NodeJS features.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is that compile a set of TS files into a .js + d.ts combination. e.g. the following creates `out.js` and `out.d.ts`

```
tsc a.ts b.ts --out mod.js --declaration
```

And then (hopefully) the following will work:

```
///<reference path="mod.d.ts">
var mod = require('mod')
```

Comment: AH interesting point you raise, I do generate a *.d.ts from my current pipeline. So if I were to just compile them all as internal modules then require them via the d.ts that will give me the intellisense and compile time safety but I was hoping to get away from using the `///<reference>` syntax. Will have a play with this idea though as this seems better if I can require the d.ts file as an exported module rather than having to write a wrapper for my internal modules.